# Firebase doc не воспринимает путь заданный с помощью полученного useRouter id в next.js

Tags: typescript, firebase, nextjs

Хочу получить данные о проекте, но не могу сделать это динамически, просто не воспринимает id, помогите пожалуйста.

```
const router = useRouter();
const {projectID} = router.query;
const getProject = doc(firestore, `projects/${projectID}`);
```

Если указывать статически - `` const getProject = doc(firestore, `projects/CEtVpthX9zMqUsyYSjEQ`); ``, то все работает.

Comment: Если что я проверял строки с помощью console.log(===) показывал true